# grunt-svgmin - how to remove fill="none"

Tags: svg, gruntjs

I am trying to configure grunt-svgmin to remove the `fill="none"` attribute that is automatically added to transparent SVGs when exported from Adobe Illustrator.

I currently have the below configuration:

```
svgmin: {
        options: {
            plugins: [
                {
                    removeViewBox: false
                }, 
                {
                    removeUselessStrokeAndFill: {
                        removeNone: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    removeEmptyAttrs: true
                },
                {
                    removeTitle: true
                },
                {
                    removeAttrs: {
                        attrs: ['xmlns', 'id', 'data-name']
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'static/images/svgs/',
                src: ['**/*.svg'],
                dest: 'static/images/svgs/'
            }]
        }
    }
```

I was under the impression that the removeUselessStrokeAndFill plugin with the option of removeNone would be what I needed to have in order to remove `fill="none"` but it isn't working.

Does anyone have any suggestions / advice on what I need to do to get this working?

Thanks,
Jess

Answer (score 2):

`fill="none"` is not useless for two reasons:

1. The default for fill is [`black`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillProperty).
2. It is an inheritable property, so if for example you had this fragment

   ```
   <g fill="none">
       <rect width="100" height="100" />
       <circle r="50" fill="red" />
   </g>
   ```

   the rect would get a transparent fill, while the circle would be rendered red.

The option you quote has another function: if a grafical element has neither a visible stroke nor a visible fill, the **whole element** is deleted.